# converting css hover to jquery hover

Tags: jquery, hover, jquery-animate

I am building a website with hover effects. See http://vitaminjdesign.com/index.html and look at the services section in the bottom right. I am using :hover to change the background color. I want to use jquery to acheive the same result with an elegant fade. Here is my html:

```
<div class="iconrow">
   <a href="#"><img src="images/icon1.png" border="0" width="35" />
   <h2>Website Design</h2></a>
</div>
```

(repeated 6 times with different images and text)

Basically, when .iconrow is rolled over, I want the background to change from none to background-color: #cccccc; and when it is rolled off, back to none.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Note: I built and tested my solution via Firebug to work on the link you provided. If you follow these steps in order,  you should have it fully working**

You will not be able to animate from `transparent` to a color except in Safari and Firefox 3.5 and other browsers that support RGBA background colors. If you are looking for a cross browser support, then I would attack the problem like this:

**1.** Have your default hover effects scoped by a non-js class, so the `:hover` effects will work as a fall-back. A great way to do this is as follows:

```
<html class="no-js">
   <head>
     .... meta, title, link tags ...
     <script type="text/javascript">document.documentElement.className = "js";</script>
     .... other scripts ...
   </head>
```

This changes `no-js` to `js` before the page even displays.

**2.** Use jQuery to add dummy elements along side your `a` tags (`js` to add the dummy element is in step 3)

Here is the CSS to use:

```
.js .iconrow { background: none !important } /* Hide current hover effect */

.iconfader {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
  -moz-border-radius: 10px;
  background-color: #ccc;
  z-index: 5;
}

.iconrow { position: relative } /* Spans are absolute, need the parent to be relative */
.iconrow a { position: relative; z-index: 10} /* Needs to sit on top */
```

**3.** Fade in and out the new dummy element on `mouseenter` and `mouseleave`

```
$('.iconrow').each(function(){
   var $span = $("<span class='iconfader'></span>").css('opacity',0.0).appendTo(this);
   $(this).hover(function(){
       $span.stop().animate({opacity: 0.8}, 200);
   }, function(){
       $span.stop().animate({opacity: 0.0}, 200);
   });
});
```

Finally, be careful if you decide to use an image background instead of the solid color. IE7 and IE8 cannot alter the opacity of 24bit PNG files. It completely screws up the transparency.

Comment: this doesnt seem to do it either. Im looking for a very simple hover effect. When you rollover a div, that div changes its bg color from one to another. It changes with a simple fade. Is there an alternate way?

Comment: @JCase11 You are not changing from one color to another. You are changing from `no color` to a color. This requires alpha transparency of a color which is only supported in a few browsers. I am not sure what didn't work since I tested it an believe I got your desired effect. Let me post some code, give me 5.

Comment: @JChase11 Do one of these two pages do what you want? http://pixelgraphics.s3.amazonaws.com/stackoverflow/1851141/vjd1.html or http://pixelgraphics.s3.amazonaws.com/stackoverflow/1851141/vjd2.html . I am guessing the second link. Please explain how what you want is different so we can provide better help. Additionally, your `scripts.js` file is calling `mc.init()` and that is throwing an error which stops the code block on the page from working.

Comment: @JChase11 by the way, your design is coming along nicely. It really looks great!

Comment: the second one is spot on!! I really appreciate your kind words and your help.

Comment: as far as the PNG graphics go, ive used some solutions that make them work in IE, but I know its not the best way to go about it. Im gonna ask another question seeing what the best practices are. THanks!

Answer (score 4):

You'll need the jquery color animation plugin: http://plugins.jquery.com/project/color

And then some code like this

```
$(".iconrow").hover(
    function() {
        $(this).animate( { "background-color": "#ccc" }, normal );
    },
    function() {
        $(this).stop(true, true).animate( { "background-color": "#fff" }, normal );
    }
);
```

**EDIT:**

Per dcneiner's comment, if you want the final color to be none, you'd have to add a callback function to the animation to change the color to "none" after it's done animating. I'm guessing animating to "none" is undefined. You can change #fff to a color close to your background to help smooth the final transition.

The animate signature is:

```
animate(params, [duration], [easing], [callback])
```

Comment: jQuery UI also allows you to animate background colors

Comment: @Joel the OP wants to go from `none` or fully transparent to a color. This type of animation won't help him. Additionally, you need to either quote `background-color` or use `backgroundColor`. Your current code is invalid JS.

Comment: @dcneiner: Thanks. As for the "none", you can get pretty close with a callback function.

Comment: yea, this isnt gonna do it. appreciate your comment tho

Comment: its not gonna do it because the background is a transparent png and no color will match it perfectly.