# anchor linking to a certain position of the page

Tags: jquery, html, hyperlink, anchor

I have an anchor link which links to another page. When it is clicked, by default it goes to the top of the next page. I want it brought to a certain position of the page. How do I do this (either with a jQuery slide effect or normal html)?

For instance, when .sample a is clicked I want it to bring you to a certain position of the linking page.

Comment: NOTE- all of the preceding solutions will not work due to the nature of my situation. Because I am using this jquery content slider, it does not function properly. It is very difficult to explain, so please visit vitaminjdesign.com and click on the services buttons. It is hashed to a particular content slider frame on the target page, but the window isn't  positioned properly on click. Any other options that allows you to specify an y coordinate of the target page?

Comment: I don't see a target anchor link on http://vitaminjdesign.com/about.html#about for instance, that's why it is positioned at the top.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, so this answer is very specific to your problem.

The reason none of the other solutions worked is that your `div` elements that would match the anchor are hidden when the page loads.

To prove this out, click on of your links on the home page, and see it *not* work. Then change the hash from `#whatever` to `#bgaboutbody` and you will see it work properly.

So, using something like this will make it work for you. Basically, if there is a hash, it will animate down to the correct spot. Put this in a script block at the very bottom of your page (right above the `</body>` tag)

```
window.setTimeout(function(){
    if(window.location.hash){
        var $target  = $(window.location.hash).closest("#bgaboutbody");
        if($target.length)
            $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: $target.offset().top}, 1000);
    }
}, 100);
```

**Learn to use fallbacks:**

It is always better to make sure your content will load without JavaScript on a sales site like this. (In a web app I feel that is a different discussion). I would recommend using the solution I gave you to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1851141/converting-css-hover-to-jquery-hover/1851260#1851260) where you add a `js` class to the `html` element in the `<head>` of the page. Then scope your CSS like this:

```
.js #contact, .js #about, etc { display:none }
```

So it will only be hidden if JS is present. Additionally, since *this* solution is also using JavaScript its important they are visible if JS is disabled so it still works.

Comment: Thanks again dcneiner. I just tried putting it on the index page containing the anchor. It didnt seem to work. The content loader doesnt seem to select any content at first. You have any luck with this?

Comment: Ah, my bad. I had an error in my code :( I updated the code here, but also try http://s3.amazonaws.com/pixelgraphics/stackoverflow/1851141/vjd_sub.html#contact or http://s3.amazonaws.com/pixelgraphics/stackoverflow/1851141/vjd_sub.html#networks . Additionally, on those links I changed the `100` ms delay to `300` ms.

Comment: brilliant! That does it. Once again, you have come through. Can I hire you?

Answer (score 14):

Use an anchor like this in your target document:

```
<a name="anchor1"></a>
```

or

```
<a id="anchor1"></a>
```

and in your source document:

```
<a href="http://www.example.com/some/page.html#anchor1">Go to anchor 1</a>
```

or within the same document:

```
<a href="#anchor1">Go to anchor 1</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

First thing you'll have to do is to define an anchor somewhere in the target page:

```
 <a name="myAnchor" />
```

Let's say the target page is called "website.html". You will then have to append the anchor to the link:

```
 <a href="website.html#myAnchor">Click here</a>
```

Best wishes,
Fabian

Comment: At a glance, I thought you were Jon Skeet then.

Answer (score 1):

here is my solution.

```
        $('.container').on('click', function(e){
            var hash        = $(this).find('a').attr('href'),
                target      = $('html').find('p'+hash),
                location    = target.offset().top;

            $('html, body').stop().animate({scrollTop: location}, 1000);

            e.preventDefault();
        });
```

html would be like:

```
<div class="container">
   <a href="hash">click me</a>
</div>

<p id="hash"></p>
```

So when clicked on the anchor it will scroll to the respective anchor in the document.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with simple html using the hash url "#". For example:

```
<a id="somelocation"></a>
```

Can be auto-scrolled into view by clicking a link like:

```
<a href="#somelocation">Go to somelocation on this page</a>
```

This can be done with links to other pages too.

```
<a href="someotherpage.html#somelocation">Go to somelocation on someotherpage</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the [name attribute](http://www.w3schools.com/HTML/html_links.asp).

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for a better way to do this, but I cannot find one. My solution was to create a zero-width anchor at the target point, pull it out of normal flow via "position: relative" and make sure that the content box was as high as it needed to be to force the following element farther down on the page:

```
<a name="target" style="position: relative; padding-top: 200px">&#x200B;</a>
```

Pulling it out of normal flow keeps the padding from becoming part of the page, but when calculating the offset all the browsers I tested respect it when positioning. Of course, this only works for fixed offsets from the top of the viewport. It works, but it feels kludgy.