# Linking to a certain position of another page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a mainpage called index.html with a menu linking to certain positions (parts) on this mainpage. This is done via the variable 'data-slide' (see below) that is behind the 'buttons' in the menu. This works well on the mainpage. However, how can I do this when I'm on another html page than the mainpage, jumping to a certain position (part) of the mainpage?

```
    <div id="nav" class="right">
        <ul class="navigation">
            <li data-slide="1">Home</li>
            <li data-slide="2">Products</li>
            <li data-slide="4">Trade fairs</li>
            <li data-slide="6">Company</li>
            <li data-slide="8">Careers</li>
            <li data-slide="10">Contact</li>
            <li class="clear"></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

Javascript:

```
var links = $('.navigation').find('li');
slide = $('.slide');
button = $('.button');
mywindow = $(window);
htmlbody = $('html,body');

slide.waypoint(function (event, direction) {

    dataslide = $(this).attr('data-slide');

    if (direction === 'down') {
        $('.navigation li[data-slide="' + dataslide + '"]').addClass('active').prev().removeClass('active');
        $('.navigation li[data-slide="1"]').removeClass('active');
    }
    else {
        $('.navigation li[data-slide="' + dataslide + '"]').addClass('active').next().removeClass('active');
    }
});

mywindow.scroll(function () {
    if (mywindow.scrollTop() == 0) {
        $('.navigation li[data-slide="1"]').addClass('active');
        $('.navigation li[data-slide="2"]').removeClass('active');
    }
});

function goToByScroll(dataslide) {
    var goal = $('.slide[data-slide="' + dataslide + '"]').offset().top;
    if (mywindow.scrollTop()<goal) {
        var goalPx = goal + 1;
    } else {
        var goalPx = goal - 1;
    }
    htmlbody.animate({
        scrollTop: goalPx
    }, 2500, 'easeInOutQuint');
}

links.click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    dataslide = $(this).attr('data-slide');
    goToByScroll(dataslide);
});

button.click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    dataslide = $(this).attr('data-slide');
    goToByScroll(dataslide);

});
```

Comment: can you not just manually "trigger" a click on event on the appropriate link or button? http://api.jquery.com/trigger/

Comment: This could help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21600425/navigate-to-anchor-on-another-page

Answer (score 0):

```
window.setTimeout(function(){
    if(window.location.hash){
        var $target  = $(window.location.hash).closest("#bgaboutbody");
        if($target.length)
            $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: $target.offset().top}, 1000);
    }
}, 100);
```

**Please try this link:-[anchor linking to a certain position of the page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1854218/anchor-linking-to-a-certain-position-of-the-page)**

Comment: sorry but can you explain your tip a little bit more?