# Jquery Fade Effect On Form Input Focus

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, textarea

this question is similar to my previous hover question ([converting css hover to jquery hover](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1851141/converting-css-hover-to-jquery-hover)) but the answer will be different because it involves a click function and two bgs.

I am building a contact page, and when the user clicks on one of the input fields, I want the background of the input to fade from one bg to another. You can see it here: [Contact Page](http://vitaminjdesign.com/contact.html)

I currently have added this code to make most of the inputs fade on click, but the textarea wont work:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    if(window.jQuery){jQuery(function(){
        (function(){ jQuery('input.name').bind('focus', function(event, ui){var target = jQuery('input.name'); target.animate({'backgroundColor':'#b1b1b1'},250,'linear')});})();
        (function(){ jQuery('input.name').bind('blur', function(event, ui){var target = jQuery('input.name'); target.animate({'backgroundColor':'#CFD2D2'},250,'linear')});})();
        (function(){ jQuery('input.email').bind('focus', function(event, ui){var target = jQuery('input.email'); target.animate({'backgroundColor':'#b1b1b1'},250,'linear')});})();
        (function(){ jQuery('input.email').bind('blur', function(event, ui){var target = jQuery('input.email'); target.animate({'backgroundColor':'#CFD2D2'},250,'linear')});})();
        (function(){ jQuery('input.website').bind('focus', function(event, ui){var target = jQuery('input.website'); target.animate({'backgroundColor':'#b1b1b1'},250,'linear')});})();
        (function(){ jQuery('input.website').bind('blur', function(event, ui){var target = jQuery('input.website'); target.animate({'backgroundColor':'#CFD2D2'},250,'linear')});})();
        (function(){ jQuery('input.area').bind('focus', function(event, ui){var target = jQuery('input.area'); target.animate({'backgroundColor':'#b1b1b1'},250,'linear')});})();
        (function(){ jQuery('input.area').bind('blur', function(event, ui){var target = jQuery('input.area'); target.animate({'backgroundColor':'#CFD2D2'},250,'linear')});})();
    })};
</script>
```

Any ideas on how to do this correctly, and makeing the textarea work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A textarea is a `<textarea>` element, not an `<input>` element. Use `'textarea.area'` instead of `'input.area'`.

Answer (score 5):

To optimize your code a bit:

```
$('input.name, input.email, input.website, textarea.area').focus(function() {
    $(this).stop().animate({ backgroundColor: '#b1b1b1' }, 250);
}).blur(function() {
    $(this).stop().animate({ backgroundColor: '#cfd2d2' }, 250);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Color plugin is needed to animate colours :

http://plugins.jquery.com/project/color